# smsGatway Api the php code has errors

Tags: php, sms-gateway

I am integrating my website with my phone to send sms using smsGatway.me i have already downloaded the apk every thing is fine the problem is with the php code i have downloaded from their website it has many errors 
This is the oho code

```
<?php

class SmsGateway {

    static $baseUrl = "https://smsgateway.me";


    function __construct($email,$password) {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

     function createContact ($name,$number) {
        return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/contacts/create','POST',['name' => $name, 'number' => $number]);
    } 

    function getContacts ($page=1) {
       return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/contacts','GET',['page' => $page]);
    }

    function getContact ($id) {
        return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/contacts/view/'.$id,'GET');
    }


    function getDevices ($page=1)
    {
        return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/devices','GET',['page' => $page]);
    }

    function getDevice ($id)
    {
        return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/devices/view/'.$id,'GET');
    }

    function getMessages($page=1)
    {
        return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages','GET',['page' => $page]);
    }

    function getMessage($id)
    {
        return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/view/'.$id,'GET');
    }

    function sendMessageToNumber($to, $message, $device, $options=[]) {
        $query = array_merge(['number'=>$to, 'message'=>$message, 'device' => $device], $options);
        return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/send','POST',$query);
    }

    function sendMessageToManyNumbers ($to, $message, $device, $options=[]) {
        $query = array_merge(['number'=>$to, 'message'=>$message, 'device' => $device], $options);
        return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/send','POST', $query);
    }

    function sendMessageToContact ($to, $message, $device, $options=[]) {
        $query = array_merge(['contact'=>$to, 'message'=>$message, 'device' => $device], $options);
        return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/send','POST', $query);
    }

    function sendMessageToManyContacts ($to, $message, $device, $options=[]) {
        $query = array_merge(['contact'=>$to, 'message'=>$message, 'device' => $device], $options);
        return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/send','POST', $query);
    }

    function sendManyMessages ($data) {
        $query['data'] = $data;
        return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/send','POST', $query);
    }

    private function makeRequest ($url, $method, $fields=[]) {

        $fields['email'] = $this->email;
        $fields['password'] = $this->password;

        $url = smsGateway::$baseUrl.$url;

        $fieldsString = http_build_query($fields);


        $ch = curl_init();

        if($method == 'POST')
        {
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsString);
        }
        else
        {
            $url .= '?'.$fieldsString;
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , false);  // we want headers
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $result = curl_exec ($ch);

        $return['response'] = json_decode($result,true);

        if($return['response'] == false)
            $return['response'] = $result;

        $return['status'] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close ($ch);

        return $return;
    }
}
```

?>

and the error from wammp is like these

[image: THE ERROR FROM WAMP SERVER]

DOES IT HAS ANY THING WITH CURL I HAVE ALREADY ENABLED CURL BUT STILL HAVE THE ERROR ...PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: maybe you have a lower php version that does not support shorthand array yet, just simply change it to `array(blah blah blah)`

Answer (score 0):

You may have earlier version of php. That's why array format [1,2,3] doesn't work.

Try Change

```
$this->makeRequest('/api/v3/contacts/create','POST',['name' => $name, 'number' => $number]);
```

to

```
$this->makeRequest('/api/v3/contacts/create','POST',array('name' => $name, 'number' => $number) );
```

Do the same to all arrays in your code. So change from [] format to array() format.

And for your function parameters from format $options=[] to just $options

Answer (score 0):

Karlo, a little note here:

> And for your function parameters from format $options=[] to just $options

Correct way would be from $options=[] to $options=array(), so the variable remains optional. By doing your way it will become mandatory.